# jQuery: Returning the value of a checkbox as an array?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, checkbox

This has got me stumped. I can easily get the value of a multiselect as an array, and pass it to an ajax request:

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">
  <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
  <etc>
...
$countries_input = $("#countries");
var countries = $countries_input.val();
$.ajax({
  data: {
    country : countries,
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

but I can't find any equivalent way to get the values of a *checkbox* with multiple selections. The obvious stuff doesn't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="foo1"/>foo1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="foo2"/>foo2<br/>
...
var bar = $('input:checkbox[name=check]').val();         // undefined
var bar = $('input:checkbox[name=check[]]').val();       // also undefined
var bar = $('input:checkbox[name=check]:checked').val(); // also undefined
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Wrap your attribute selectors in quotes.  `$('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').val();`

Comment: Thanks guys - I learnt a lot here. I don't like the 'answer tick' thing, but gave it TJC, because he got in a minute earlier... :) I do like the jsFiddle thing, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in jQuery function for that. You have to do it yourself. You can do it easily enough with a simple loop:

```
var vals = []
$('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').each(function() {
    vals.push(this.value);
});
```

Or if you only want the checked ones:

```
var vals = []
$('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        vals.push(this.value);
    }
});
```

Or you can use `map` and `get`:

```
var vals = $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Or if you only want the checked ones:

```
var vals = $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').map(function() {
    return this.checked ? this.value : undefined;
}).get();
```

---

Side note 1: jQuery requires the value in an attribute value selector (the kind above) **always** be in quotes, although as of this writing despite documenting that it's still lax about it. It's a jQuery thing, but in this case you'd need it for CSS as well ([CSS2 Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) | [CSS3 Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)) because your value includes `[]`, which aren't valid for values without quotes in CSS. (In CSS, without quotes the values must be [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).)

---

Side note 2: Note I used `this.value` in the iterator functions above to get the value of the `input`, rather than `$(this).val()`. It's pretty much just a style thing, neither is better than the other from all perspectives. `this.value` is more direct and if you know the DOM at all (and every web programmer should), it's perfectly clear. But of course, while perfectly reliable cross-browser with checkboxes and most other `input` elements, it isn't reliable cross-browser with some other form fields (`select` boxes, for instance). `$(this).val()` is more idiomatic in a jQuery-intensive application, and you don't have to worry about whether `this` is an `input` or a `select`. Yes, it adds overhead, but if you don't have thousands of them, it's not like it's going to matter.

Comment: You don't need to escape the square braces if you put your attribute selector in strings, like [you're supposed to](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/): `$('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').val();`.

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks. Curiously, I was just thinking "Hey, wait, I forgot that jQuery wants quotes" (it's a jQuery thing, not a CSS thing).

Answer (score 4):

- If you are not familiar with the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method, let me introduce one of my favorites. The example on the manual page also features checkboxes. The `.get()` method can be used to transform a jQuery collection into an object.

> **.map():** Pass each element in the current matched set through a function,
>   producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

- Other knowledge you need is that you have escape `[]` with backslashes inside the attribute selector: `name=check\[\]]`. **Edit:** Of course if you use the standard attribute selector syntax, there will be no problem: `name="check[]"`

Something like this would suffice:

```
var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mL9SY/1)

Comment: You don't need to escape the square braces if you put your attribute selector in strings, like [you're supposed to](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/): `$('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').val();`.

Comment: @Rocket Thanks, seen your comment under TJ's answer and already started to correct mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would think `serialize()` and `serializeArray()` array would work, but apparently they apply only to children of the selection.

Worst case I would just use `map()` to get the array like so

```
country : $("your input selector").map(function() {return $(this).val();})
```